# What causes the difference between calc and cellStats in raster calculations in R?

Tags: r, gis, raster

I am working with a dataset that consists of 20 layers, stacked in a RasterBrick (originating from an array). I have looked into the sum of the layers, calculated with both 'calc' and 'cellStats'. I have used calc to calculate the sum of the total values and cellStats to look at the average of the values per layer (useful for a time series). 
However, when I sum the average of each layer, it is half the value of the other calculated sum. What causes this difference? What am I overlooking?

Code looks like this:

```
testarray <- runif(54214776,0,1) 
# Although testarray should contain a raster of 127x147 with 2904 time layers. 
# Not really sure how to create that yet. 

for (i in 1830:1849){
  slice<-array2[,,i]
  r <- raster(nrow=(127*5), ncol=(147*5), resolution =5, ext=ext1, vals=slice)
  x <- stack(x , r)
}

brickhp2 <- brick(x)

r_sumhp2 <- calc(brickhp2, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
r_sumhp2[r_sumhp2<= 0] <- NA


SWEavgpertimestepM <- cellStats(brickhp2, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE)
```

The goal is to compare the sum of the layers calculated with 'calc(x, sum)' with the sum of the mean calculated with 'cellStats(x, mean)'.

Rasterbrick looks like this (600kb, GTiff) : http://www.filedropper.com/brickhp2
*If there is a better way to share this, please let me know.

Comment: Can you make a minimal self-contained reproducible example? Should be easy to create a small array and take it from there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure I can. The array is quite weird in its structure as its extracted from a netCDF file which is another model output. The following code will generate the exact number of values, I hope that suffices.

testarray <- runif(54214776,0,1)

Comment: The point is that you should not create the same number of values. Create a simple small array and show what you  want to accomplish. Only if it works on the example, but not on the actual data, we should look at the real data. Also, by making the example, you will, in most cases, answer your own question. I have added your suggestion to your question, but you have to edit it further.

Comment: Also, if the data come from netcdf, you might want to use `b <- brick("file.nc")`

Comment: Or skip the array bit altogether, but provide some data in the example, so that at least it is clear what you are comparing. There is a call the `cellStats` but it is not clear what you are comparing that with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion comes as you are using `calc` which operates pixel-wise on a brick (i.e. performs the calculation on the 20 values at each pixel and returns a single raster layer) and `cellStats` which performs the calculation on each raster layer individually and returns a single values for each layer. You can see that the results are comparable if you use this code:

```
library(raster)
##set seed so you get the same runif vals
set.seed(999)

##create example rasters
ls=list()
for (i in 1:20){
  r <- raster(nrow=(127*5), ncol=(147*5), vals=runif(127*5*147*5))
  ls[[i]] <- r
}
##create raster brick
brickhp2 <- brick(ls)

##calc sum (pixel-wise)
r_sumhp2 <- calc(brickhp2, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
r_sumhp2 ##returns raster layer

##calc mean (layer-wise)
r_meanhp2 <- cellStats(brickhp2, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE)
r_meanhp2 ##returns vector of length nlayers(brickhp2)

##to get equivalent values you need to divide r_sumhp2 by the number of layers 
##and then calculate the mean
cellStats(r_sumhp2/nlayers(brickhp2),stat="mean")
```

[1] 0.4999381

```
##and for r_meanhp2 you need to calculate the mean of the means
mean(r_meanhp2)
```

[1] 0.4999381

You will need to determine for yourself if you want to use the pixel or layer wise result for your application.

Comment: Many thanks for the elaborate explanation. Seems like a combination of both functions would be best. I am working with a classification based on the total amount (pixel result) and in further steps interested in the layer result of specific classes. I can work with this.